# Reprocessing Salsa

Tags: canning, food-processing

I was using a new canner for the first time and while processing salsa I could not get the 10 pound control to jiggle. I processed for approximately an hour and the canner was under pressure during that time.

All the lids are sealed but I’m not sure they reached the 10 pounds of pressure required. I now know that the weight was not on all the way.

Should I reprocess the salsa? It has been 8 hours since I processed them.

Comment: It's rare to need to pressure can salsa- it's usually acidic enough to just use hot water bath canning. Can you post your recipe?

Comment: @Sobachatina Careful, at-home cooks don't have a way to know for sure. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/82807/how-to-know-if-a-recipe-is-acidic-enough-for-storage-bottling

Comment: @SnakeDoc- Of course. With all canning it's important to follow a proven recipe- and that's why I asked for the recipe. Salsa recipes generally call for enough tomatoes and added acid (usually lime juice) to put them well into a safe acidity. I actually find it hard to imagine a salsa that basic enough to require pressure canning.

Answer (score 1):

212 degrees for an hour is still adequate to preserve your salsa for a year or so (12-18 months)

at 10 PSI your boiling point would have been increased to 242 degrees which would decreased the amount of time needed in the pressure cooker  - The hour you used is enough for a quart jar size at both temperatures

Re-processing it a second time would likely degrade the texture of your delicious hand-made creation
Follow all other safe canning practices and you should be good to go

Hope you enjoy!